# How to update user table, whenever user viewed email, sent through php?

Tags: php, mysql, email

Please check following scenario,

- First I am sending email to user using php
- Whenever user viewed this email, I want to update my user table.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd put some resource to your email (like an image/tracking pixel) that is loaded from your server. The url of that resource is actually an url to your script. Once the client app tries to load the resources your script gets executed. You get the params you set when sending the email and do what you want with them.

Keep in mind that not all email clients will behave this way. For example plain text email viewers will not load any resources.

Comment: I.e how to load a virus

Comment: what are you talking about? tracking pixels are quite comkon practice and images inside emails are fine too